# FlexSlider - Execute "next" action

Tags: javascript, html, flexslider

I'm currently developing a responsive website using flexslider. The address of the test version is here:
http://residentsecurity.daniel-lucas.com/

When the site shrinks down to tablet / mobile version an icon appears showing the user that by sliding their finger on the slider they can go to the next/previous image.

I've tried turning this icon into a link so that if the user clicks on it, it will go to the next slide.

I thought that by inserting

```
<a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
```

the script for flexslider would use the link to go to the next slide but it's not working.

Does anyone know how to turn make this link work with flexslider?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an answer to this question but instead modified the css of the next button that already exists to adapt it to my needs on mobile phones.